# Set default paste to Keep Text Only

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2003, microsoft-office-2003

When I paste into Word 2003 the default is `Keep Source Formatting`. How can I change the default to `Keep Text Only`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Word 2003 doesn't let you set "Keep text only" as a default.

But you can create a macro as described in detail here: https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/word-keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-unformatted-text/

Essentially you:
1. create the macro.
2. add the macro to your template.
3. assign a keyboard shortcut to the macro.

That way, if you want to paste text only you can just use the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is definitely not an ideal solution, but it does work

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar need so I wrote an [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that creates a global "paste text only" option. It's not perfect but it's fairly effective. There's a special case for Excel and you could probably create one for Word as well.

```
; Key: Win+V
; Cmd: Paste unformatted text
#v::
IfWinActive Microsoft Excel
{
   Send !es{Down 2}{Enter}  ;Edit menu, Paste Special, Text only
   ; This still works in 2007 and 2010 even though the Edit menu doesn't exist anymore
}
Else
{
   clipOld := ClipboardAll  ;Save the entire clipboard
   clip := Clipboard        ;Save just the text portion of the clipboard
   Clipboard := clip        ;Replace the clipboard with just the text portion
   Send, ^v                 ;Paste the text
   Clipboard := clipOld     ;Replace the clipboard with its original contents
}
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

In Word, select Options...Advanced. Under Cut, copy, and paste, set all the "Pasting" settings to Keep Text Only.

[image: Keep Text Only in Word]
*(Screenshot is from Word 2013)*

Comment: The question is for Word 2003